# QT doesn't display previous build warnings unless the entire project is rebuilt

Tags: qt, build, warnings

I'm not sure if this is standard behavior for IDEs, but I personally find it irritating. If a file produces warnings when built (unused variables, mismatched ints/longs/etc.), those warnings will cease to be displayed if another file is modified and the "Build project" button is clicked. Doesn't it make more sense for warnings pertaining to unmodified code to continue to be displayed? Is there a way to force this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings are displayed when the compiler emits them -- unfortunately, that's the design decision taken by both VS team (up to 2008 at least) and by Qt Creator team.

It seems to be standard behavior, and I don't know of any options to override it. It should be easy to fix in Qt Creator, but may be hard to fix in Visual Studio unless relevant APIs are present. For VS you'd need to write an add-in and there would need to be an API available that gives you read-write access to the error list *and* to the build process. If such APIs exist, then it'd be a simple thing to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is "standard behavior", and more specifically, behavior is an attribute of how build systems on Earth "are-designed-to-behave".

As @Kuba notes, the warnings are emitted by the compiler.  They aren't stored (except in the "log-of-all-errors/warnings" for the build operation, which the IDE typically never reads-back-and-excerpts-from-for-future-build-operations, which would get their own log of their new warnings/errors).  Thus, you won't see the warning again unless the compiler actually compiles the file again, and that's because they would be *new* warnings that are generated again by the new build operation.

To get what you want (a clever thought, IMHO), the build system would need to:

- store warnings from each file-compile (probably on a "per-file-basis")
- recall/display those warnings each time that file-output-product was "used"

Very clever.  I'm not aware of any system that does that.  It would require fairly significant IDE or build-tool-level management of build products, which IMHO, none of them do well (but some are better than others).

This is the year 2012, and not only are we missing our flying cars, but we're missing build systems that merely/quickly build-only-what's-required-using-all-cores while easily handling different configurations.  Both were expected by now.

Then, sometime after that, you could probably get your feature.  That would be a bonus, because then you could use it in your flying car.

Comment: As I've said, the build system doesn't have to do any of it -- the IDE does. It'd be a simple modification to the IDE, too. Couple hundred lines at most, I expect.

Comment: @Kuba, it's the build system or IDE.  The IDE is the proxy for the build system. Not sure that it could be a couple hundred lines -- we'd need a database that stores messages hashed from the build file and configuration, and a clever algorithm that decided when/how to "look-up", since we can mix debug/release products into an EXE, different compile settings for intermediates to the same EXE, some warnings depend on what did the including/using, especially for all template-stuff. A 60/40 or 70/30 solution might be cheap-and-useful, though.

Comment: All IDEs have such a "database". I'm sure in case of both Qt Creator and Visual Studio, there's a model class that consumes the parsed messages, and there's a view that displays them. The view is named "Error List" in VS, and "Issues" in Qt Creator. Right now the model is cleared upon a rebuild, and that's what has to change -- it needs to be cleared for each file only when there are new messages indicating that the file was built. You're almost making me add this to Qt Creator just to show it's fairly simple to do.